# Sending Facebook like button via Ajax call Not Working

Tags: php, ajax, facebook

I'm working on a project that involves infinite scrolling page. In this, I'm sending the whole  of boxes and appending it after the previous/last  on the page. So, it creates a list of vertical boxes one below the other.

Here's my PHP code that is sent to Javascript during ajax call:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($result)) {
        echo "<div style=\"margin-bottom:15px;\" class=\"confession_box\">";
        echo "<div style=\"font-size:17px;\">";
        if($row['name'] != "") { echo $row['name'].', ';} if($row['age'] != "") { echo $row['age'].', '; } if($row['sex'] != "") { echo $row['sex'].', '; } if($row['location'] != "") { echo $row['location']; }
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<div style=\"font-size:13px;margin-top:8px;\">Posted on: ".date("D, d M y h:i A",strtotime($row['date_time']))." </div>";
        echo "<div style=\"margin-top:20px;font-family:calibri;\">".nl2br(htmlspecialchars($row['confession']))."</div>";
        echo "<div style=\"margin-top:20px;\">";
        echo "<div id=\"fb-like-count\" style=\"float:left;width:105px;\">";
        echo "<div class=\"fb-like\" data-href=\"https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/\" data-width=\"100\" data-layout=\"button_count\" href=\"http://www.confesstalk.com/post.php?id=".$row['confession_id']."\" data-action=\"like\" data-show-faces=\"true\" data-share=\"false\"></div>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "<div id=\"comment-count-display\" style=\"margin-left:50px;\">";

        $comm_countcomm = "select count(*) from comments where confession_id=".$row['confession_id'];
        $result_countcomm = mysql_query($comm_countcomm,$conn);
        $row_countcomm = mysql_fetch_assoc ($result_countcomm);
        $countcomm = $row_countcomm['count(*)'];
        echo "<a href='post.php?id=".$row['confession_id']."'>".$countcomm." comments | Post New Comment</a>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
```

And below is my Javascript code to handle this ajax response:

```
$('#end_confbox').after(data);
```

The problem is that: everything is getting displayed on the HTML page except the Facebook Like Button which is:

```
echo "<div class=\"fb-like\" data-href=\"https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/\" data-width=\"100\" data-layout=\"button_count\" href=\"http://www.confesstalk.com/post.php?id=".$row['confession_id']."\" data-action=\"like\" data-show-faces=\"true\" data-share=\"false\"></div>";
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that your code just creates the markup for the like button. But the like button is actually generated by the facebook js sdk code, which gets run when the page loads. 
Thankfully, there is a method in the Facebook JS SDK which instructs it to check for new markup and generate the widgets required:

[FB.XFBML.parse](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/)

Comment: Great. Thanx. Atleast I got to know the bug. Can you please instruct me to integrate this FB parse into my webpage. Actually, I'm in shortage of time, so I need this to be done quickly. Thank you.

Comment: @cipherux You just need to add `FB.XFBML.parse()` in your javascript code after you add the markup to your page.

Comment: @cipherux I'm sorry, I can't look at your website right now. But the solution is adding one simple line of code after your code adds the ajax response to the page.